# sorting a multidimensional array by date with different index

Tags: php, date, array-multisort

i want to sort an multi-array by date, but it's a bit particular.
there are two type of entries in the array :

```
 if array[i][0] == 'note' then the date is array[i][7] 
 if array[i][0] == 'activity' then the date is array[i][5]
```

is it possible to do that with array_multisort?

Comment: Can you show us the `var_export($array, true);` ?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to make a keyarray for dates

```
  $name_key = array();
 for($a=0 ; a<count($array);$a++)
 {
 if(array[$a][0]=='note')
 $name_key[$a] = array[$a][7];
 }
elseif(array[$a][0]=='activity'){
 $name_key[$a] = array[$a][5];
 }
```

then you need to multisort according to it

```
array_multisort($array,SORT_ASC,$name_key);
```